# How to create a folder in a destination path equal to the number of folders in source path

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a path: `C:\Project\files`- this directory will contain a folders starting with name `MD_`. So these folders are gonna get created dynamically, so i wont be knowing the complete name of the folder and also how many numbers of folders will be generated.
so i want to copy the number of folders starting with MD_ to a destination path and i want to create a folders equal to the number of folders in source path and the destination path folder name should be sequential like `1,2,3..`

Comment: [xcopy /T](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) copies folderstructure, but no files.

Comment: Show us some code !

Comment: Show us some example